# Who are all of the "Democrats in Menendez’s chamber" and for that matter, what exactly is a "chamber" in this context?

Tags: united-states, senate, terminology, house-of-representatives, new-jersey

CNN's September 23, 2023 [Rep. Andy Kim announces he’ll run against NJ Sen. Bob Menendez in wake of his indictment](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/09/23/politics/menendez-andy-kim-senate/index.html) includes the following passage:

> Many New Jersey Democrats swiftly called for the senator’s resignation, including Gov. Phil Murphy, who said, “The alleged facts are so serious that they compromise the ability of Senator Menendez to effectively represent the people of our state.” Murphy would have to appoint a senator to replace Menendez should he resign.
>
> Other members of the New Jersey delegation in Washington, DC, have also called on Menendez to resign. Democratic Rep. Mikie Sherrill said, “There is no room for this kind of conduct in public service.”
>
> **Democrats in Menendez’s chamber** have been slow to comment on the indictment, including junior New Jersey Sen. Cory Booker. But Pennsylvania Democratic Sen. John Fetterman on Saturday became the first senator to call for Menendez’s resignation.
>
> Menendez made it clear in a statement Friday evening that he does not intend to resign.

From the passage I conclude that the two US Senators from New Jersey Menendez and Booker are in this "chamber" but since "Democrats" is plural, and Menendez was not slow to comment, there must be others.

And I'm assuming that the separate reference to "Other members of the New Jersey delegation in Washington, DC" refers to New Jersey members of the House of representatives.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Who are all of the "Democrats in Menendez’s chamber", and for that matter, what exactly is a "chamber" in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I'm assuming that the separate reference to "Other members of the New Jersey delegation in Washington, DC" refers to New Jersey members of the House of representatives.

You've put most of it together. "Democrats in Menendez’s chamber" contrasts with discussion of the reaction of members of the House of Representative. It refers to the Senate, as opposed to the House:

> The legislative branch of the federal government consists of the Congress, which is divided into two chambers -- the Senate and the House of Representatives.

https://georgewbush-whitehouse.archives.gov/government/legi.html

Also:

> Bicameralism is a type of legislature that is divided into two separate assemblies, chambers, or houses, known as a bicameral legislature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicameralism

The term "camera" comes from the Latin word for "room" (side note: "camera" in the sense of something that takes pictures is a shortening of "camera obscura", or "dark room"). The word "chamber" also ultimately derives from "camera", but through French, which added the h.

Answer (score 3):

'Chamber' in this context means the Senate Chamber (as opposed to the House Chamber). This phrase is just another way of saying 'Democratic senators'.

Comment: Ah, like [6-22-75, baby](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64446150#64446150) I simply could not parse the sentence properly. Yes, had it said "Senate Democrats have been slow to comment..." it would have gotten the job done just as well, but I suppose the author thought "Why say something clearly when you can *say it fancy?*" I wonder if this comes from a "CNN style guide" similar to The Economist's. [1](https://www.economist.com/films/2021/07/09/how-to-write-well), [2](https://www.benjaminjameswaddell.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/the-economist-style-guide.pdf) (humor)

Comment: @uhoh: Sophisticated verbiage is the *sine non qua* of journalistic aesthetics. Or in other words: they do so love dem big words...

Comment: @uhoh I suppose the author may have wanted to make explicit the same-part-of-congress relationship between other senators and Menendez rather than trusting readers to make the connection.  In that case it might have been better to say "Menendez' Democratic colleagues in the senate" or something like that.  But I have a bit of sympathy for journalists working on tight deadlines.

Comment: @phoog we can love the journalist and dislike the sentence at the same time; I have a hunch journalists do that too!